# Twitter POS and NER: What is state-of-the-art?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

What is the current state-of-the-art for pos tagging and named entity recognition for twitter data? Are industrial-strength programs like `Spacy` and `SparkNLP` accurate for such texts? How about `FlairNLP` and Stanford's `CoreNLP` accuracy measures?

Comment: this is good question however it borders on being opinion-based

Comment: There are metrics to determine SOTA, about spacy and other modules I agree with you, it's a mostly a matter of personal preference and/or contingent project needs.

Answer (score 6):

SOTA is changing so rapidly in NLP that even Data Science professionists struggle to cope with it. I have two main sources that I constantly check to gain some insights on SOTA:

- [NLP Progress](https://nlpprogress.com/) from Sebastian Ruder. It contains updates on NLP on a whole lot of subfields, NER and POST included.
- Paper with code contains [a section on NLP](https://paperswithcode.com/area/natural-language-processing). That's a great website for ML in general.

I know these links do not tackle the problem of Twitter specifically, however I don't think that domain is qualitatively different from others. IMO, of course.

---

About your other question:

> Are industrial-strength programs like Spacy and SparkNLP accurate for such texts? How about FlairNLP and Stanford's CoreNLP accuracy measures?

As I wrote above, it's mostly a matter of personal preference and/or contingent project needs. There's no right or wrong tool. Personally, I found Stanford tools to be the best, for either the quality of their predictions and the amount of models available from a single pipeline. But as I said it's very subjective.

Comment: Thanks @Leevo. I have been following NLP Progress site as well. Given the unique challenges that Twitter text presents, I was wondering about whether any of these models have been tested and how they fare.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sorry I don't know of sources specifically on Twitter models. What makes it different from more general NLP tasks? (I'm just curious, I'm goinig to work on Twitter data very soon.)

Comment: This presentation details the difficulties with Twitter data: https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun16/module-2-socmed/5.pdf

Comment: Also check this: http://derczynski.com/sheffield/papers/ner_issues.pdf